# Risk to be rejected on custom UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar, appstore-approval

I'm wondering if there's any risk to see the app rejected from the AppStore (iPhone app) if I modify the existing UITabBar making it slightly taller. I'm working on a custom uitabbar with custom background pattern that is also just a little bit taller (8px) than the default one. It additionally has a raised central button.

I really don't see why this could reject the app but I thought I would better ask first since it's quite a lot of work implementing this custom design and I might have overlooked some of the HIG guidelines/rules.

Many thanks,
Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of apps in the AppStore with custom tab bars, starting with some of the most popular ones like [Instagram](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Finstagram%2Fid389801252%3Fmt%3D8&ei=drpBTv5LxtOyBvHckMwH&usg=AFQjCNFSW2eQwoZ8L1-IJj330e7oOQ_3DQ&sig2=oNRZ3qj4XOn3ANxUhnjSVg) so you should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

There are huge numbers of apps out there with custom tab bars, including non-standard sized ones and ones with protruding central buttons. They're fine, as long as they work correctly.